# Discord.NET Not Responding to Certain Command (C#)

Tags: c#, json, discord, discord.net

I'm attempting to create a discord bot with discord.net that grabs all variant Ids from a store and sends a discord messages with them formatted like so:

```
var1
var2
var3
etc
```

After testing, I found a way to grab and deserialize the data, however due to limitations with discord, I'd have to use the RunMode Async in order to prevent them from closing the connection. When using this and trying to execute the command, the bot returns no response. Here is my code for the command:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Commands;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using QuickType;

namespace ShopifyATC.modules
{
    public class VariantScraper: ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        
        [Command("variant", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
        public async Task Variant(string varUrl)
        {

            var shopifyId = await GrabShopifyVar(varUrl);
            var bip = "";
            

            
            while (shopifyId.Product != null)
                foreach (var variant in shopifyId.Product.Variants)
                {
                    bip += $"{variant}\n";
                }
            
            
            static async Task<Temperatures> GrabShopifyVar(string varUrl)
            {
                var httpClient = new HttpClient();

                var variantGrabRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri(varUrl += ".json"),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get
                };
                variantGrabRequest.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36");

                var variantGrabResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(variantGrabRequest);

                var variantGrabContent = 
                    await variantGrabResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var variantGrabResponseData =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Temperatures>(variantGrabContent);
                return variantGrabResponseData;
            }

            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(bip);
            Console.WriteLine("n");
        }
    }


}
```

Any idea as to how to fix this or why it's happening? If I don't use the RunMode Async discord closes the connection and returns the following:"A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task."

Thanks,

- Mo

Comment: Simply debugging your code would have shown you the infinite loop issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop never stops so your operation never completes. This is why the command blocks.